# How to modify a file in Facebook

Tags: facebook

I looked up this question and it says to click on the three dots by the file and modify will show on the new Facebook. It does not. I only have the option to download or see original post. I pinned the post to the top of the group and the modify option is not there either. I now have 6 versions of the same file in my group, and would really rather not have more.